# how can I check when a webhook exists and then not create it?

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-api

I can successfully create a webhook or more webhooks. But every time I call auth it executes the webhook.register so every time it creates a n webhook. I want to avoid this and I only want to create a webhook when no webhook exists. How can I do it?

code:

```js
const handleWebhookRequest = async (
  topic: string,
  shop: string,
  webhookRequestBody: string,
  webhookId: string,
  apiVersion: string,
) => {
  const sessionId = shopify.session.getOfflineId(shop);

  console.log('H');
  console.log(webhookId);
  console.log(sessionId);
  
  // Fetch the session from storage and process the webhook event
};

shopify.webhooks.addHandlers({
  PRODUCTS_CREATE: [
    {
      deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
      callbackUrl: '/webhooks',
      callback: async (topic, shop, body, webhookId) => {
        console.log('--- Product update ---');
        const payload = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(payload);
        console.log('--- /Product update ---');
      },
    },
  ],
  PRODUCTS_UPDATE: [
    {
      deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod.Http,
      callbackUrl: '/webhooks',
      callback: handleWebhookRequest,
    },
  ],
});

app.get('/auth', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    // The library will automatically redirect the user
    await shopify.auth.begin({
      shop: shopify.utils.sanitizeShop(req.query.shop, true),
      callbackPath: '/auth/callback',
      isOnline: false,
      rawRequest: req,
      rawResponse: res,
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.send(e);
  }
});

app.get('/auth/callback', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  // The library will automatically redirect the user
  console.log('CALLBACK');
  const callback = await shopify.auth.callback({
    rawRequest: req,
    rawResponse: res,
  });


  const response = await shopify.webhooks.register({
    session: callback.session,
  });

  console.log(response);

  if (!response['PRODUCTS_CREATE'][0]?.success) {
    console.log(
      `Failed to register PRODUCTS_CREATE webhook: ${response['PRODUCTS_CREATE'][0].result}`,
    );
  }
  
  console.log(callback);

  res.send('AUTH');
});
```

I am very thankful for your help and hope anyone can help me to solve this issue